# How do I resolve getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found. when trying to call a gRPC function through grpcurl?

Tags: grpc, grpc-c#, grpcurl

I'm currently trying to call a function from a gRPC server using gRPCurl, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to dial target host "https://server.com": dial tcp: lookup tcp///server.com: getaddrinfow: The specified class was not found.
```

My grpcurl command looks like this:

```
 grpcurl -vv -protoset .\Project.protoset https://server.com Namespace/GetNumber
```

I've tried adding the port number to the URL, but it returns an error saying too many colons. How can I resolve this error? I'm happy to provide more details.

Answer (score 1):

The "too many colons" message is the clue.

You're currently providing an address like `https://server.com`. This will be parsed as `host= https, port= //server.com`.

Drop the https, as it's not part of the address. Provide the address as a simple `host:port` parameter.